# Change default font in DreamWeaver on OS X

Tags: macos, dreamweaver

I just bought a new macbook pro 15'. This is my first mac. I really hate the Apple font in dreamweaver or when I'm doing any kind of coding. I can't read it. I should buy glasses but in the mean time is there any way to change the font and font size of dreamweaver? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, you should ask this on superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Dreamweaver CS5:

- Go to Dreamweaver > Preferences, and select the Fonts category. You'll see the currently set code font next to "Code view:".
- Dreamweaver ships with Monaco 7 as its default code font, but you can change it to be anything you'd like.

If you're running an older version of Dreamweaver your preferences may be slightly different, but the general principle should still apply.